# Can't get Ext.ux.form.SearchField to work in ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs

I can't quite seem to get the SearchField to work in extJS. I want to implement it in the table toolbar, and perform the filter on my table store object.

I have my require setup like this :

```
Ext.require([
    'Ext.ux.form.SearchField'  
]);
```

I add the search field to my toolbar like this :

```
tbar: [

  new Ext.ux.form.SearchField({
       store: tablestore,
       width:320
  })
]
```

And my tablestore is pretty ordinary. I set the remoteFilter to false (I just want this happening locally).

```
var tablestore = new Ext.data.SimpleStore({
    fields: [
        {name: 'id', type: 'int'},
        {name: 'name'}
    ],
    remoteFilter:false
});
```

When I click on the filter button, the list is cleared. If I remove the filter the list remains cleared.. there is no error message.

Fiddle :

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/6hs

(make sure you have version set to 4.2)

**EDIT:**

here is another fiddle. In this fiddle I am using the search field as a docked item. It still has the same problem:
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/6p4

Comment: Can I ask you where you found this SearchField? I couldn't find it in the ExtJS documentation.

Comment: its the standard search field in ExtJS isn't it? Or is there some other search/filter field that should be used.

Comment: @AurélienThieriot it's in the 'ux' section of the api - it's an extension bundled with the framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As recommended by Andrei, I ended up writing my own Search Field.

I added a property called 'filterMeOut' to the record object, and then later applied my own customer filter using **filterBy** on the **tableStore** object.

Inside my items array in my docket Items I made this code

```
    }, 'Search', {
        xtype: 'textfield', enableKeyEvents: true, listeners: {
            keyup: function (string) {

                tablestore.clearFilter();

                var dataToDelete = [];

                //iterate and set flag
                tablestore.each(function(rec, idx){
                    contains = false;

                    for (field in rec.data) {

                        if (rec.data[field].indexOf(string.getValue()) > -1) { //field contains
                            contains = true;
                        }
                    }
                    if (!contains) {
                        rec.filterMeOut = false;
                    }else {
                        rec.filterMeOut = true;
                    }
                });

                //custom filter object
                tablestore.filterBy(function(rec, id) {
                    if(rec.filterMeOut) {
                        return true;
                    }
                    else {
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

Works perfectly for me.

Comment: although I do have a problem with rendered values :(

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to write you own searchfield, if you use it often. As you see [in the code](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.2a/examples/ux/form/SearchField.js), this is a simple extension that sets a parameter (with the default name `query`) in the proxy and reloads the store.
In your case it does not work because you use a `SimpleStore` (and `SimpleStore.load()` loads an empty store (even it has some records)).

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do what you try to do but I used this small plugin instead:

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?70558-Ext.ux.grid.Search

It's probably not perfect (No SenchaCmd packages, not easy to update) but it works perfectly with Grid filters and without the need to specify a store (It will use the Grid parameters)

You have to add this as a "Grid Plugin" and unfortunately dive into the source code to find more information about the configuration.

Comment: I can't find this in the us.grid directory. Do you mean I have to download it myself and add it to the directory?

Comment: Yes. It's a pain so I would understand if you don't want to do it. But  I made it work so I guess it's an improvement :/